# multiple audio players on one page

Tags: html5-audio, audio-player

I've made 2 audio players on 1 page and that doesn't seem to work well...

For some reason the second audio player doesn't work but instead it seems to control the first player...

The code is similar except this:

1st one:

```
<head>
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
```

2nd one:

```
<head>
    <title>Music Player 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player2.css">
</head>
```

Probably somewhere down to code I should make more differences, but I don't know where...
Thanks for you help.

ps. I'm a musician and not a programmer, so that explains this probable silly problem.

Comment: Could you show us the code where the audio player is? It should be in an audio tag like this: <audio src="something.mp3"></audio>

Comment: first player:  <audio src="http://koenplaetinck.com/onewebmedia/17%20Praeludium%20%26%20Fuga%20in%20B%20Flat%20Major%2C%20BWV%20866_%20I.%20Praeludium.mp3" id="song"></audio>

Comment: 2nd player: <audio src="http://koenplaetinck.com/onewebmedia/Cherry%20Blossom.mp3" id="song2"></audio>

Comment: Does adding the controls property do what you want? Should look like this: <audio src="koenplaetinck.com/onewebmedia/Cherry%20Blossom.mp3" id="song2" controls></audio>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Eric. tried it, but unfortunately still the same...